# "Terminal like" text view XCode Swift 4

Tags: macos, textview, swift4, xcode9

I am writing a simple application that should implement the TELNET protocol.

I got to the point where I have to implement the console-like text behaviour. I need the following:

- Something that prints out the message **from** the remote host (Different options available)
- Something that gets my message **to** the remote host (Doable with an external text field)

What I am trying to achieve is a single text view/field that prints the output, gets my input in the same view, and doesn't let me edit the previously printed text (just like a regular terminal window)

I tried with a (scrollable)TextView, tweaking the isEditable field on and off, but it does not appear to be what I am looking for.

This is what appears to the user once the connection is established
[image: Default Text]
This is what happens when the user press backspace.
[image: Edit to avoid]

I would also like to prevent the editing of all the text written before the last return key.

Am I checking out the correct container? Is there something more suitable for my need?